# Add custom fields to Shipping Cart Price Rule and Catalog Price Rule

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules

I want to add one boolean field in each of Promotion Rule. Please can anyone suggest me how to proceed and which Model/Block need to be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Copy Main.php from

/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Catalog/Edit/Tab/Main.php
To
/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Catalog/Edit/Tab/Main.php

In function _prepareForm you can add your custom field:

```
$fieldset->addField('custom_boolean_field', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Custom Field'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Custom Field'),
            'name'      => 'custom_boolean_field',
            'required' => true,
            'options'    => array(
                '1' => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Yes'),
                '0' => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('No'),
            ),
        ));
```

Comment: Only this much?

Comment: Yes, Field will reflect in catalog promotion form, Also save.

Comment: Is that works ?